# UPS Standard Gateway URL Stopped Working

Tags: shipping, ups

Starting this AM, our Magento 2 store stopped pulling in UPS rates. We were using the standard gateway https://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi

Does anyone know if this was deprecated and went down? It would have been nice to get a heads up! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that starting after 10pm EST on May 23, 2023, the UPS rates stopped working for us as well.

To address this problem, we have temporarily switched to using our FedEx account for shipping rates until we can find a resolution for the UPS integration. This workaround has been working for us in the meantime.

I've read that switching the "UPS Type" to "United Parcel Service XML" dropdown option has been working for some. Stores > Configuration > Sales > Delivery Methods.

We had to do a combination of switching to UPS XML as well as "Revalidate Your Access Key". In UPS account https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit > Manage Access Keys > Revalidate Your Access Key

Comment: i have the same problem, switching to type UPS XML, it start calculating rates, but shows 5 methods, not the one i want to show.